# AWS SDK S3 Delete bucket not working

Tags: php, aws-sdk

Trying to to delete a bucket with 2 html files on it, I folow this code.

but I am getting an error.

> **Fatal error**:  Class 'ClearBucket' not found in

```
    require '../aws/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

    $client = new S3Client(array(
        'credentials' => array(
            'key'    => $aws_access_key,
            'secret' => $aws_secret_key,
        ),
        'region'  => $aws_region,
        'version' => 'latest'

    ));


    $clear = new ClearBucket($client, $bucket);
    $clear->clear();


    // Delete the bucket
    $client->deleteBucket(array('Bucket' => $bucket));

    // Wait until the bucket is not accessible
    $client->waitUntil('BucketNotExists', array('Bucket' => $bucket));
```

Comment: Try to use full namespace while creating an object. $clear =  new Aws\S3\Model\ClearBucket($client, $bucket)

Comment: still has an error <b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Aws\S3\Model\ClearBucket' not found in

Comment: check in your sdk for class and apply correct path.